# llvm replace a function with another one

Tags: llvm, jit

I am trying to replace a function call with another one. e.g. here is the code with 3 functions - print1, print2 and main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
extern "C" { 
int print1()
{
   printf("Inside print1\n");
   return 0xdeadbeef;
}
int print2()
{
   printf("Inside print2\n");
   return 0xbeefdead;
}
int main(void)
{
   return print1();
}
}"
```

My goal is to replace use of print1 (in main) with print2. I compile the above code into an llvm::Module* (called main in the code below) and then create an execution engine out of it.

```
std::string errMsg;
llvm::ExecutionEngine *ee =
   llvm::EngineBuilder( main ).setErrorStr( &errMsg ).create();    
ASSERT_NE( ee, nullptr )<<"Execution engine is nullptr:"<<errMsg;
```

At this point, I am able to get all the 3 functions (print1, print2 and main) from the execution engine and am able to execute them fine. However, problem occurs when I try to replace function "print1" with "print2", as follows:

```
llvm::Function *print1f = main->getFunction( "print1" );
llvm::Function *print2f = main->getFunction( "print2" );
llvm::Function *mainf = main->getFunction( "main" );

//carry out the replacement
print2f->takeName( print1f );
ee->freeMachineCodeForFunction( mainf );
ee->freeMachineCodeForFunction( print1f );
print1f->replaceAllUsesWith( print2f );
print1f->deleteBody();
print1f->dropAllReferences();
print1f->eraseFromParent();

//run main
void *mainfPtr = ee->getPointerToFunction( mainf );
mainfPtr = ee->recompileAndRelinkFunction( mainf );
ASSERT_NE( mainfPtr, nullptr );
ret = ((int(*)(void))(mainfPtr))();
*EXPECT_EQ(0xbeefdead, ret);*
```

However, ret is returned as 0xdeadbeef, as if print1 is being called and not print2. Can someone please let me know if I am following the right steps to replace the function call. If there is other method, please let me know.

thx
Vikas.

==========

Comment: Can the compiler do any inlining before this point?  (If it did, `main` would effectively have `print1`'s code pasted into it, and replacing the function by name wouldn't be able to do much with that...)

Comment: Good point cHao, however, I am not running any optimization passes or inlining when compiling the module. It is simply constructed using ParseAST routine (http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/ParseAST_8h.html), so I am guessing that no inlining happened. Is there a way to ensure that no inlining happens?

Comment: cHao, you were right. The compiler was indeed inlining print1. Thanks for your help.

Comment: cHao, it seems I cannot accept a comment as an answer. Please post your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the compiler were to inline `print1` in `main`, the function would never actually be *called*;  Instead, `main` would have its own private version of `print1`'s code pasted in.  Since it doesn't actually have to refer to the shared `print1` anymore, swapping in `print2` might not affect `main`'s behavior.

If you want to verify that this is the problem (and/or keep it from happening, if it is), try telling the compiler not to inline.